# Creating a static menu with CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am trying to create a website that contains a static menu and separate content using iframes.
So far, I have been able to successfully create the iframes, but I want the menu iframe to change the content in the other iframe.
I realize what I want will require possibly AJAX or JQuery.
 Here is my code for the index: (HTML)

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/topg.css" />
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe class="menu" src="menu.html"></iframe>
<iframe class="mainContent" src="start.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is `/css/topg.css`:

```
body {
background-color: #333333;
}
p {
color: #AAAAAA;
}
h1 {
color: #AAAAAA;
}
a:link {
color: #FFFFFF;
}
a:visited {
color: #CCCCCC;
}
a:hover {
color: #00FFFF;
}
a:active {
color: #FFFF00;
}
li {
color: #AAAAAA;
}
.menu {
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
}
.mainContent {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
iframe {
margin: none;
padding: none;
border: none;
}
```

Comment: IFrame is obsolete since html5 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: @Vinz243: That’s wrong, [`iframe` is part of HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-iframe-element). However, it is _not_ a good solution to build whole pages on. @user3578907: Go look at solutions to include your menu into several different pages from one central location, preferably server-side ones.

Comment: you should use a frameset doctype and look for info/tutoriel how to build prperly this kind of out of age html document. Else use ajax or better a scripr server to include your different section of document/pages

Comment: @Vinz243 If you read the document, only one setting attribute was deprecated for HTML5. Lol

Comment: OK, I apologize, I read a bit too quickly. However, it is indeed not recommended. And playing with navigation based on iframe is a mess...